# Push Notification not working in ios 9.2.1

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios9.2.1

I have integrated push notification in my app. I have tested it in ios7, ios8, ios9.2.1. Its working perfectly in few devices and few ios9.2.1 devices don't get device token even. Please Help.

Comment: I am agree with you. I have same problem.

Comment: in iOS 9 faced many issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889878/does-my-app-display-second-time-notification-ios-9

Comment: If anyone have any solution then please help.

Comment: @User267 have you got the solution for this?Even I am facing similar issue

Comment: Yes @Sujania. It was my silly mistake. We have to options for login in our app. So in social login i was not sending devicetoken to my server. So the social login users were not getting notifications. :S I didn't changed anything in notification code.

Comment: Thank you for the response...Actually with this issue apple has rejected my app twice even though I m providing Facebook login as optional..

Comment: So is it working in some devices or its not working at all?

Comment: It is working in many devices but not in few of our client devices..

Comment: Same problem was mine. In client's device it was not working. But then i got it was my mistake. And he was using facebook login.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104274/discussion-between-sujania-and-user267).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized where was my mistake. I was not sending device token while using social login. Silly mistake.
Its working fine now!