# Receiving multiple Duplicate Push notifications from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing a serious issue, I am receiving multiple push notifications from the server? Even the server is sending once.

I read on stackoverflow different posts that its due to calling

> application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

I checked and debugged the app, this method is calling only once in the AppDelegate.

Any suggestion will be helpful for me?

Comment: Are you sure the method is called only once, and not every time when application is launched?

Comment: application.registerForRemoteNotifications() for registering your device for remote notification for device key, u can get unique device key with it. there is no issue with this method

Comment: Is the issue related to a specific version of iOS? We had the duplicate push issue as well (related to `registerForRemoteNotifications `). Only reproducible on a specific version of iOS 9. If you are facing this issue only on iOS 9, it might be related to `registerForRemoteNotifications `. Cannot remember what we did to fix it, though.

Comment: no I checked, most of the people faces this issue

Comment: on launching application, this should be called everytime but only once in the lifecycle....

Comment: Guys I solved this issue, I am going to add the best explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-There are certain reasons behind this issue, most of the solutions are "call once in the app "**registerForRemoteNotifications**". 
First, check if you are not calling this method more than once in AppDelegate

-In my case, I debugged and checked my code, I am calling only once the above method.
from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33935224/2915785) I realized, during development, I am again and again pulling "ipa" to the phone, let's check this solution if it works

1. First Uninstall your app from the phone
2. Install the app again, and check by sending push again

Now, in my case everything is just fine now, Xcode has this bug started in iOS 9 and till iOS 11, developers facing this issue. I hope if these above two solutions help you in understanding the problem.